# The designer cannot be displayed for this file because none of the classes it contains can be styled

Tags: visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I have a project developed in Visual studio 2015 and VB.Net

I opened it with visual studio 2015 and after making a small change that had nothing to do with the configuration I closed it. When reopening it also with Visual Studio 2015 it does not find any reference and it does not show me the design of any form.

The references exist, in fact if I delete one and select it again it gives the same problem with the selected one.

Error: The designer for this file cannot be displayed because none of the classes it contains can be styled.

I have Visual Studio 2015 and Visual studio 2022 installed on my computer in case it had something to do with it

I've tried reselecting the references but it's still the same.
On each reference it tells me:

If I open it with Visual Studio 2022 it opens correctly

Thank you

Greetings,

Comment: The Winforms designer used to be quite buggy in older versions of VS. So just stick with VS2022 and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have already solved it.
I have uninstalled the .NET Standard Support for Visual Studio 2015 (x86) package

I had installed it days before doing some tests, I opened the project and it worked but once it was compiled something changed that I couldn't open it correctly again.
Once uninstalled I can open it correctly and compile it without problems